# Knockout mapping array with different types of view models

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

Having an array of different types of items:

```
var items = [{{type:t1,text:"abc"},{type:t2,data:"123"}}]
```

and view models:

```
function T1VM(t1) { ... }
function T2VM(t2) { ... }
```

How can I use the mapping plugin to map items to an observable array of matching view models?

Comment: What do you mean a "matching view model"?  Do you want the first view model mapped to the second?  Or the second to the first?  Or do you have a third view model you want the other two mapped to?

Comment: Objects with type: "t1" should be mapped to T1VM etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was too easy!

```
var mapping = {
    create: function (options) {
        if (options.data.type == "T1")
            return new T1VM(options.data);
        else if (options.data.type == "T2")
            return new T2VM(options.data);
    }
};
```

And then:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(items, mapping);
```